# How do I omit a parameter in a JScript ADO/ASP classic method call?

Tags: asp-classic, ado, jscript

How do I omit a parameter in a JScript ADO/ASP classic method call?

For example, a `RecordSet` object has a `GetString` method (e.g. `recordset.GetString(StringFormat, NumRows, ColumnDelimiter, RowDelimiter, NullExpr`), where all parameters but the first are optional.

If I want to skip a parameter in VBScript (e.g., use the default for one parameter) I can do `recordset.GetString 2, , "|"`, or use named parameters.

However, it doesn't seem like I can do the same with JScript. I've tried using `null` for the optional parameter, using an empty string (`''`), omitting it entirely (as with VBScript), and using JSON-style named parameters, with no luck.

Am I missing something, or is this not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in pure JScript. To use the default parameter values, you need to explicitly specify these values in the method call (provided, of course, that you know what these values are).

A possible option is to use a mix of JScript and VBScript code, e.g. call the `GetString` function from VBScript and return its result to JScript. Some examples (that should give you the idea): [WSH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1657971/113116), [HTA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3342683/113116), [ASP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10080262/113116).

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answer, Helen. I also appreciate the alternative solutions you list (though I always try to avoid VBS).

Answer (score 2):

If you believe [this statement](http://p2p.wrox.com/archives/xml_databases/2001-11/3.php)

> In VBScript, it is legal to omit parameters to function calls, by
>   writing  a comma only, as in:
>
> adoCmd.Execute , , adExecuteStream
>
> In JavaScript, this is not legal, but in all cases so far, we have
>   been  able to work around that in some way, mostly by specifying null
>   or zero in  place of the missing parameters.

you can avoid to mix languages, if you come up with a specific strategy for each ADO method call. For your .GetString() case, the appropriate zilch value is -1. My evidence for the correctnes of this (*specific*) solution:

- -1 'works' in VBScript too
- other funny numerical values (0, -10) - and (surprisingly) undefined - throw 'Operation is not allowed' errors
- "" and null throw a type error